# how to make new texstudio and pdf viewr communicate?

Tags: texstudio, viewers

I installed new version of TeXStudio and it does not communicate with the PDFViewer, currently I am using foxitreader. Before I installed the new one it was fine.

Comment: Did you check the TeXStudio settings, if the right viewer is configured? Might be a dumb question, but why don't you just use the internal one?

Comment: even the internal viewer could not  display the pdf

Comment: could not display is does not display?

Comment: -1 because too many details are missing. Which version is "new version"? Which PDF viewer? Which operating system? What does "does not communicate" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled foxitreader, then I reinstalled it, and reconfigured TeXStudio with this external viewer and it works. I think it was an internal communication error.